# Deleting files functionality with Jhipster

Tags: branch, delete-file, jhipster

I've found that you cannot actually delete an entity, so I was thinking of doing a jhipster utility to delete entities (and find for relations, then cut them too), and if said searching works then add one to change an entity name.

That said, I was looking where I can find in jhipster generator the files that take domain over the file creation.

Answer (score 0):

JHipster supports deleting an entity as its repositories extends JpaRepository, and its generated REST controllers also expose a delete action.

Comment: Then what command do you use to delete a whole entity?

Mostly asking because everyone insists that jhipster does NOT have a way to delete entities via a line of code (like how you use jhipster:entity to make a whole entity)